# Is there any solution on using id as url in django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I was doing some blog related site and wished for a blog to appear when its id is provided in the URL. Overall the code seems fine but it keeps on saying page not found. Can anyone help me with the problem?

I tried searching in the internet but couldn't get any specific solution. It works when id is not given but says page not found when id is given.

url script for blog:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allblogs, name ='allblogs'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/',views.details, name='detail')
]
```

views script for blog:

```
def details(request,blog_id):
    detailblog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk = blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/details.html', {'blog': detailblog})
```

Error message:

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7k1s.png)

Comment: What URL are you using? Do you have a blog with that ID? Show the full error.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/blog/1/
Using the URLconf defined in Portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
blog [name='allblogs']
blog <int:blog_id>/ [name='detail']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, blog/1/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Thats the error and yaa I had 2 simple blogs with in my database which i was trying to retrieve.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to check the id you are trying to use, sometimes when we create a the same app in a project multiple of time